# CopyOnwriteArrayList alternative for frequent updates

Tags: java, multithreading

please feel free to correct me.

Scenario building a marketdata cache which requires a temporal ordering (ie. ordered by time elems are added).  Cache will have a lot of updates.

Logic dictates that a List is a logical choice given indexing is free and easy to perform things like getOldestElem list.get(0); binary search etc.

This cache will be used by multiple threads obviously reading and updating the cache which points to CopyOnWriteArrayList. (Javadoc indicates that this is not suitable for large sizes and frequent updates)

I am looking for an alternative or a better idea?

Comment: "temporal ordering... will have a lot of updates": will the updates include alterations to existing elements, or only addition of new elements?

Comment: Both addition at the back of the queue and deletion from the head for old elements.  Existing elements will not be updated.

Answer (score 3):

If exisitng records are infrequently (or never) updated, so the "frequent updates" are frequent additions, you might be able to use the temporal ordering to optimize your data structure by separating old and new elements.

For example, you could segment you cache into several `CopyOnWriteArrayList` objects, each holding no more than a fixed number of elements, and each segment holding a temporal sub-range of the data. The frequent additions would grow the last segment until it reached the maximum size, at which point you would append a new segment for subsequent updates. By keeping the maximum segment size small enough you would avoid the performance problems of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. You should hide the implementation details within your own `List` class.

---

**Edit:**
Removal of old elements similarly alters only one segment: the oldest segment.

Answer (score 2):

Best to test for your use case, but an `ArrayList` protected by a [`ReadWriteLock`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) might give you better performance.